# Enabling CORS in .ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cors

I've created an .ajax request, but I keep receiving this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.com/api/GetData. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I've looked a few things online and edited my ajax request to look like this:

```
var url = "https://api.com/api/GetData";
var data = jsonHandler();
$.support.cors = true;
this.xhr = $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    accept: "application/json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    fail: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

Is there anything that I am missing from my request?

I've seen [this SO q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688261/jquery-ajax-with-post-to-get-image-png-from-cors-enabled-server) but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing or if this is relevant to my issue.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Just tried enabling CORS in the web.config file according to [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html), but nothing changed. Will update again.

**UPDATE 2:** Adding this to the  section of web.config appears to have solved my issue:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Are you sure the receiving API accepts CORS requests?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan aha.. hmm better go check on that. might have to delete this post. thank you.

Comment: That server should set 'access-control-allow-origin' header

Comment: @terbubbs The server has to specify where it allows CORS requests from

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem, I solved this issue at my server side code, not in the ajax request. in my case; I am using `cakePHP` at server side.

I added this code to my php controller.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. I added this to my web.config file (in proper format) and the CORS Blocked message disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this very same issue a while back. And I did not need to enable/activate CORS as I've read that some firewalls will strip out the headers for security. http://promincproductions.com/blog/server-proxy-for-cross-site-scripting-cors/

In a global part of your js code, add in a function ...

```
window.googleDocCallback = function () { return true; };
```

Then, to the URL in your AJAX (GET assumed?) request, if you have no URI params, append ?callback=googleDocCallback

and if you do have other params, append `&callback=googleDocCallback`

For more info, please see: https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/

Comment: I'll get back to you on this after I try a few things

Comment: I gave this a try and received the same Content-Origin Request Blocked with the updated URL (appended with &callback=googleDocCallback). Perhaps I am not placing the window.googleDocCallback in the right place. What exactly is the global part of my js code? The .js file I am writing is part of a UserControl (ascx) resource, and I am just creating a script source in the ascx markup. Does the googleDocCallback need to be placed elsewhere in my project?

Comment: Global refers to a place in the code where other functions can access it without getting any `item or object is undefined` errors.  To test if you've placed the function global enough place, set a basic variable and give it a value. If you can reach that variable (meaning the variable is defined) then you're in a global-enough place.  Check the console log or other places to look for anything undefined.

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation. It appears that Erasmo's answer solved my issue. I will upvote you anyway as this might be helpful and possible solution for others.

Comment: @terbubbs Thanks for the upvote. Erasmo, I'm upvoting your answer as well,

Comment: @Adam T : How can assume it as GET where the type is set to POST ?

Comment: @Hari not sure i understand your question. If it helps, for the issue I encountered, I was making a GET request.

Comment: @Above: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to say that the question was about type:POST  and your answer is related to GET. How could you assume as GET ?

Comment: Oh, yes. Now I understand your point. Not so much an assumption, my answer provided insight as to how I solved it as I encountered it - which was a get request. Perhaps same approach (added callback var as post data key/value) can be applied to POST but not sure